# Android Realm, why I don't have any of delete methods available?

Tags: android, realm

I'm learning Realm library and building DAO class. Switching from tutorial to tutorial and all of them containing some type of delete method like `deleteFromRealm();` or `deleteAllFromRealm();`. While I'm doing everything just like in tutorial including adding dependency on build.gradle:

```
 compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.84.1'
```

but I don't have any of methods with delete word, there are only few called removeItem etc but according to the internet those methods are deprecated in favor of delete methods which I mentioned above.

Does my dependency compile old version of realm? if so, which is the most current ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because you are using a very outdated version of the realm plugin. Try `compile 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.0.0'`.

Realm also has a very good official [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)